# How can I use SQL to populate a child table with a value from the parent?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Problem] (
    [ProblemId]       INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]           NVARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Problem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProblemId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProblemId]        INT              NOT NULL,
    [Title]            NVARCHAR (100)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionId] ASC)
);
```

I have two tables. The Problem table has the Title field populated.

How can I populate the Title field of the Question table with the Title of the Problem table ?

Comment: What is the goal of having a duplicated title?

Comment: It's a temporary measure to populate the field with a starting point. In future there will be a disconnect between the two but right now I need to at least have something.

Comment: Ok, it was just to be sure that you're aware about the bad practice of having duplicate information like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
UPDATE q SET q.[Title] = p.[Title] 
FROM Question q 
INNER JOIN Problem p ON p.[ProblemId] = q.[ProblemId]
```

However it is usually not a good practice to store duplicate data.